# Calculate Linear ODE constant coefficients knowing the curve

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I have a function $f(x)$ defined in $\Bbb R$ with $f$ smooth and I would to find the linear differential equation with constant coefficients that generates it (or at least the best fit of it).

The order of the equation can be $n$ as high as you want but $n$ is finite.
The LCCODE Is surely not a base of $\Bbb C$ infinity if $n$ is finite.

I am thinking more of a numerical approach maybe with machine learning.
It is like a fit but for functions.

Comment: In what way is your function $f$ given? If you want to compute with it, it has to be in a format that can be passed to a computer.

Comment: You have the function but for the numerical approach we can sample It (Shannon Theorem)